# Power BI API Admin Scopes 401 Unauthorized

Tags: rest, powerbi, admin

I'm trying to get the Tenant.Read.All and Tenant.ReadWrite.All scopes when authorizing with the PBI REST API but I can't figure it out. I can get a token using Postman that contains every other scope but the two required for Admin calls to the API. I'm not using a service principal, just signing in when Postman gets a new token.

[image: I have every scope added with permissions on the Azure app.]

Comment: Which API specifically?

Comment: Power BI REST API, specifically the [admin requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin).